# .Net Core 2.2 update to .Net Core 3.1 causing HTTP Error 500.31 due to missing assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

We've updated our current .Net Core 2.2 web app to .Net Core 3.1 and now get the following error when debugging locally:

*HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies*

*The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.*

*Specific error detected by ANCM:
Error: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.NETCore.App.deps.json) was not found: package: 'runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App', version: '3.1.5-servicing.20270.5' path: 'runtimes/win-x64/lib/netcoreapp3.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll'*

The error seems to be fairly straight forward - the System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll assembly is missing. The problem is that I'm unsure why it's not being found when debugging locally anymore or how to get it working again. I've tried solutions other have posted for resolving missing dependencies issues like this, such as manually pasting the .dll in the bin folder, removing the web.config file, running the IIS Express instance as Out Of Process, or including a package reference to the file as a Nuget package directly, but nothing has helped so far.

Does anyone know what is causing this and any ways to resolve this issue?

Edit: More information added below:

When running 'dotnet --info' I get the following (note I removed older versions to keep it succinct)

```
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.5
  Commit:  65cd789777

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

This project complied and run perfectly fine locally when using .Net Core 2.2, so upgrading to .Net Core 3.1 seems to be the cause of this issue. I've tried this out on two seperate development machines as well, using the latest .Net Core 3.1 SDK runtimes and hosting bundles and both machines run into this same issue.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14443)

Comment: Does code run on machine where code was compiled?  Did you deploy the application on second machine?  How did you originally install the working code on the Core 2.2. machine?

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks for the link, I've tried out some of the suggestions in there but unfortunately hasn't worked.

Comment: @jdweng The code does build, but the IIS Express prints out that HTTP 500.31 Error. I've updated my answer with some more info to reflect this

Comment: did you deploy and run setup.exe on deploy machine?  did you read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/